# How to check a spinner which contains a string is not equal to another string?

Tags: android, equals, android-spinner

How to validate many spinners,which intially contains string select.If it is changed,then only validation must execute.Otherwise have to display some message.

```
if(!(spnVehType.getSelectedItem().toString()) .equals ("Select")|| !(spnVehType.getSelectedItem().toString()).equals("اختيار") &&
        !(spn_bodytype).equals("Select")|| !(spn_bodytype).equals("اختيار") && !(spn_veh_make).equals("Select")|| !(spn_veh_make).equals("اختيار")
        && !(spn_veh_model).equals("Select")|| !(spn_veh_model).equals("اختيار") && !(spn_mfgyr).equals("Select")|| !(spn_mfgyr).equals("اختيار") )
{
//call async task
}
```

I tried with positions,but the problem is when i set values of spnVehType.It automatically loads other spinner values(spn_bodytype,spn_veh_make,spn_veh_model).Since it automatically loads.It returns the position 0.

```
if(spncustpos!=0||spnBodyTypepos!=0||spnVehMakepos!=0||spnVehModelpos!=0||spnVehMakepos!=0||spnMfgYrpos!=0)

{
//call async task
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the selected string from a spinner and check if it's equal to another one:

```
String selectedString = (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();

if(selectedString.compareTo(anotherString) != 0) {
    // Stuff to do when strings are not equal.
}
```